# Programtcially Submit Form that Executes JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http

I have a form that allows me to select a date (year, month, day)

[image]

The HTML snippet looks as follows:

```
<form id="lottotab1" name="lottotab1">
  <input id="action" name="action" value="winningnumbers" type="hidden" />
  <input id="searchStartDate" name="searchStartDate" type="hidden" />
  <input id="searchEndDate" name="searchEndDate" type="hidden" />
  <!-- Search Date -->
  <div class="searchDate">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td/>
          <td align="center">
            <td align="center">
              <td align="center">
                <td/>
                <td align="center" />
                <td align="center" />
                <td/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <td>
              <select id="lottoStartDateYear" class="" name="lottoStartDateYear" onchange="javascript:funChangeDate()">
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select id="lottoStartDateMonth" class="" name="lottoStartDateMonth" onchange="javascript:funChangeDate()">
                <option value="01">Jan</option>
                <option value="02">Feb</option>
                <option value="03">Mar</option>
                <option value="04">Apr</option>
                <option value="05">May</option>
                <option value="06">Jun</option>
                <option value="07">Jul</option>
                <option value="08">Aug</option>
                <option value="09">Sep</option>
                <option value="10">Oct</option>
                <option value="11">Nov</option>
                <option value="12">Dec</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select id="lottoStartDateDay" class="" name="lottoStartDateDay">
                <option value="-1">Day</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>
              <!-- For Ticket: 4500 -->
              <a href="#" name="getWinningNumbers" onclick="setValueLoadGame();searchWinningNumbers();showSearch();">
                <img style="margin:0px 12px" src="/wps/PA_NYSLNumberCruncher/css/images/logo/numTrackerGoPurple.gif" />
              </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to programmatically change the date and submit form. I know I could do this using Selenium by clicking on the year/month/day and changing it like that. However, this is a hassle.

Is there any way to stimulate changing the date and clicking the 'Go" button by sending an http request in the browser?

I know the form contains various names and attributes but I am not sure how to combine these values/attributes to form a valid http request that changes the date and submits form automatically.

Further, I observed that the page executes some kind of Javascript when you select the date range does this mean it cannot be stimulated via pure http request?

Thanks

Comment: Do you own the application and can change the existing Javascript and have to implement a new feature or what are you trying to do exactly? You mention selenium which would imply you want to possibly write a test around that page?

Comment: No, I cannot change the Javascript on page.

Comment: Do you have an idea what the `setValueLoadGame();searchWinningNumbers();showSearch();` functions do?

Comment: @funcoding No. How can I find out?

Comment: Right click on the page and see the source!

Comment: Can you change the page? If so, you can include some jquery function to capture the click event of the go link and execute your function to perform your request.

Comment: Use *Ctrl+Shift+I* in Google chrome and select **Network** tab. Then set any date and click on **Go** button. Click on interesting request name and see details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the numbers data, you can get it directly.  If you open developer tools and watch the XHR requests when you load the page, you will see how the page gets the data:

http://nylottery.ny.gov/wps/PA_NYSLNumberCruncher/NumbersServlet?game=win4&action=winningnumbers&startSearchDate=04/2017&endSearchDate=06/2017&pageNo=1&last=0&perPage=50&sort=0

Comment: This answer solves my problem (+upvoted) but how can I force it to display more than one date at a time? Changing the `startSearchDate` and the `endSearchDate` doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: You should see the first 50 dates in the range as some JSON looking data.  You can increase the page size (perPage) and/or change the current page (pageNo).  Also note you can change the game (game).  Use webtools to see what string is needed for which game.  Here is a link to all of the "lotto" numbers this year for example http://nylottery.ny.gov/wps/PA_NYSLNumberCruncher/NumbersServlet?game=lotto&action=winningnumbers&startSearchDate=01/2016&endSearchDate=05/2017&pageNo=1&last=0&perPage=500&sort=0&_=1494444828055

Comment: If you'd open web tools and look as I and others have suggested, you will see that the URL for quick draw works slightly differently:  http://nylottery.ny.gov/wps/PA_NYSLNumberCruncher/NumbersServlet?game=quick&action=winningnumbers&startSearchDate=9/04/2017&endSearchDate=&pageNo=1&last=0&perPage=10&sort=0&_=1494446301770

Comment: I did exactly that. Please check the url in your previous comment there's only one day's worth of data there.. my question is how to retrieve data from range (let's say the past year) (modifying the end date does not seem to work as I stated previously)

Comment: Yes, that endpoint won't work on a range.  There's nothing you can do about it.  Fetch multiple ranges and concatenate them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If the page uses jQuery,  then you can do following in browser console:

```
$("#lottoStartDateYear option[value=2013]").attr('selected', 'true');
$("#lottoStartDateMonth option[value=08]").attr('selected', 'true');
$("#lottoStartDateDay option[value=13]").attr('selected', 'true');
setValueLoadGame();
searchWinningNumbers();
showSearch();
```